# Zandor Vorkov in "Dracula vs. Frankenstein" (1971) - Alternate action scenes with ray gun ring

Tags: deleted-scenes, dracula-vs-frankenstein

This movie is somewhat crude and tacky, yet it added a significant element of science fiction that tempered its trite monster/horror backstory. The bargain basement Dr. Frankenstein in this film sought a biochemical solution to tissue regeneration via a trauma-induced spike of adrenaline. There is a little bit of science fact in his pronouncements though like most science fiction the rest is rubbish.

I saw this film at least 30 years ago and I recall some scenes that differed from what is available now. The full-length film is easy to find on You Tube. In these uploads, Dracula (Zandor Vorkov - Roger Engel) wears a ring that gives him superpowers, the most memorable of which is the ability to emit a heat ray or lightning bolt that immolates the victim. In all of the videos I have seen, I saw Dracula use the ring that way only once. In the re-run I saw many years ago, he used the ring on several other victims and also verbally threatens to use it on other individuals to get them to comply with his demands. I vaguely recall an ending different to the classic decomposition of Dracula when he is exposed to sunlight. I am unsure about the ending but am certain that there were other scenes with Dracula employing his evil ray ring more than once. In fact I had written up a summary of my recollections of the story over a decade ago to send out by email for story ID. Any input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've edited out the answer from this question post. Please only put the answer in the answer section below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an alternate ending as described by the writer/producer of the show and on a DVD version, mentioned by a guest here. According to the guest the monster is destroyed using Dracula's ring and as the writer/producer described, Dracula is impaled on a piece of pipe. I also recall more dialog between Dracula and his would-be victims.

Here is the interview with the writer/director:

I noticed that I did not mention the specific point in the interview where the writer/director talks about the original ending, which is at the 15 minute mark.

I could not find a version of this movie with the alternate ending on You Tube, nor one with some of the cut-out scenes. If anyone could post short clips from their DVD version of the movie for others to see it would be very helpful to see that and of course it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Moderator, please re-post the comment by guest here since you removed it before I could copy the information. Thank you.